# Grails on STS: How to run >1 grails app simultaneously

Tags: eclipse, grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, run-app

The workspace consists of 2 projects. One is the main, user-facing, grails app, which runs on port 8080.  The other is an admin app, also grails, by which all kinds of stuff for the main app is configured (and I'd like to get to run, simultaneous to the main app, on 8081).

I do not know how to get the two to run simultaneously (and have failed to find the answer via google).  I want to do this, so that I could change stuff for the main app in the admin app, and test those changes in the main app, without constantly shutting down one in order to start the other.

I have tried setting the config.groovy parameter, for my local environment, to
        grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8081/admin-app"
(whereas the main app specifies grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/main-app")

I have tried adding " -Dserver.port=8081" as a program argument in the run configuration for the admin app, but this does not do the trick.

My humblest thanks to the eclipse/STS guru who has the answer to this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not add the server.port as a program argument.  It needs to be a vm argument.

VM arguments are added on the arguments tab:

[image]

So, should be added on the bottom, not the top.

Comment: Hi! Can you be more specific? I'm trying to get two applications working on different ports too (one application uses the another), but I can't have this working. How can I add the variables as vm argument and what is what I need to add? `Server / Launch Configuration / Arguments / -Dserver.port=8081` ?